# Silverlight C# show data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight

I have some mistakes with my data show in datagridview. I used C# and WCF Ssilverlight and when I use the query in SQL I can see all data but in C# I can't see all. Can anyone help me?

[image]

```
    public IQueryable<MandehMorakhasi> GetMandeMorakhasiList(int IDLanguage, int IDShobe, string Tarikh)
    {
        string RozKari = GetOption("TanzimHogohDastmozd_Other_RozKari", IDShobe).ParamValue;
        List<DateTime> DateList = new List<DateTime>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tarikh))
        {
            DateList = Helper.GetDatesOfYear(Tarikh, IDLanguage);
        }

        var TblEstMohasebe = (from s in this.ObjectContext.TblEstMohasebes where s.IDSHobe == IDShobe orderby s.TaTarikh descending select new { s.AzTarikh, s.IDEstKargozini }).ToList();

        var TblEstMandeMorakhasi = (from s in this.ObjectContext.TblEstMandes
                                    join c in this.ObjectContext.TblEstMandeSubs
                                    on s.IDEstMande equals c.IDEstMande
                                    orderby c.IDEstMandeSub descending
                                    where s.IDSHobe == IDShobe && c.Type == 3
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        s.IDEstMande,
                                        c.Mande,
                                        c.Mabna,
                                        c.MorakhasiEstefadeshode,
                                        c.MandePayanMah,
                                        s.IDEstKargozini,
                                        s.AzTarikh,
                                        s.TaTarikh
                                    }).ToList();

        List<int> IDEstKargoziniList = TblEstMandeMorakhasi.Select(x => x.IDEstKargozini).ToList();
        List<MandehMorakhasi> MandehMorakhasiList = new List<MandehMorakhasi>();

        int Count = 0;
        foreach (var i in IDEstKargoziniList.Distinct())
        {
            MandehMorakhasi Mandeh = new MandehMorakhasi();

            Mandeh.IDEstKargozini = i;
            Mandeh.IDSHobe = IDShobe;
            Mandeh.CodePersenel = (from s in this.ObjectContext.TblEstKargozinis where s.IDEstKargozini == i select s.IDMostakhdem).FirstOrDefault();
            Mandeh.NamePersenel = (from s in this.ObjectContext.TblEstPersenel_T
                                   join c in this.ObjectContext.TblEstKargozinis on s.IDPersenelEst equals c.IDPersenelEst
                                   where c.IDEstKargozini == i
                                   select s.Name).FirstOrDefault() + " " +
                                   (from s in this.ObjectContext.TblEstPersenel_T
                                    join c in this.ObjectContext.TblEstKargozinis on s.IDPersenelEst equals c.IDPersenelEst
                                    where c.IDEstKargozini == i
                                    select s.Family).FirstOrDefault();
            Mandeh.Date = Tarikh;
            Mandeh.IDLanguage = IDLanguage;

            if (IDLanguage == 1)
            {
                Mandeh.EnabledField = Convert.ToInt32((Helper.MiladiToShamsi(TblEstMohasebe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDEstKargozini == i).AzTarikh)).Substring(5, 2));
            }
            else
            {
                Mandeh.EnabledField = TblEstMohasebe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDEstKargozini == i).AzTarikh.Month;
            }

            /////////////the first month of year in hijri**strong text**
            var Mande_1 = TblEstMandeMorakhasi.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IDEstKargozini == i && (x.AzTarikh.Date >= DateList[0] && x.AzTarikh.Date <= DateList[1] &&
                x.TaTarikh.Date >= DateList[0] && x.TaTarikh.Date <= DateList[1]));

            TimeSpan MandeMorakhasiAval_1_T = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan MabnaMorakhasiPayanMah_1_T = new TimeSpan();
            if (Mande_1 != null)
            {
                MandeMorakhasiAval_1_T = (TimeSpan.FromTicks(Mande_1.Mande));
                Mandeh.MandeMorakhasiAval_1 = Helper.GetTimeSpanConverter(MandeMorakhasiAval_1_T, TimeSpan.Parse(RozKari).TotalMinutes).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm");

                MabnaMorakhasiPayanMah_1_T = (TimeSpan.FromTicks(Mande_1.MandePayanMah));
                Mandeh.MabnaMorakhasiPayanMah_1 = Helper.GetTimeSpanConverter(MabnaMorakhasiPayanMah_1_T, TimeSpan.Parse(RozKari).TotalMinutes).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm");
            }
```

Comment: So.. first things first. Do your c# lists contain any data? Use the debugger to check

Comment: yes i have,i use entity framework